# Xdebug install (php.ini) OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I have a problem enabling xdebug.

After installation it is not listed in phpinfo.

What I do:
1. sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
2. Uncommented this line of the php.ini file:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
```

3. sudo apachectl restart

After this the php stopped working, only html pages were visible.

So I do the following:
4. sudo rm /etc/php.ini
5. Uncommented this line of the php.ini.default file:

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
```

6. sudo apachectl restart

After this the php was working again, but in phpinfo was not any xdebug entry and it didn't work in Netbeans.

How can I install xdebug?

Answer (score 2):

Please use the wizard to help you figure out how to compile: http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: Compile is not working because phpize is broken in some way. But why should I compile it? Mac has xdebug already compiled, it's part of Mac installation.

Comment: the version of Xdebug that ships with 10.8.4 is 2.1.3 which I believe doesn't support tracing via the URL

Answer (score 2):

I think you also need the following settings in your php.ini file. Amyway, this is what is working for me:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp/xdebug/"
xdebug.profiler_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

Also make sure that the /tmp/xdebug/ folder and the /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so file exist.

Comment: Notice the spaces aside the equal sign in xdebug.profiler_enable will make this not work. Not sure if the capitalized "On" is also incorrect. Otherwise it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

to add to Jean-François Beauchamp answer:

to create the xdebug.profiler_output_dir

sudo touch /tmp/xdebug

also i had to create a php.ini file

sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini